# Terraform Lambda Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to build an deploy an Lambda written in Go and want to use terraform to deploy. I followed the steps on the [terraform site](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/guides/serverless-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway.html).

But the difference between that example and my app is I have multiple subroutes. When I try to call the application I get this error in the API Gateway test:

> Sat Sep 22 11:06:31 UTC 2018 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Sat,
>   22 Sep 2018 11:06:31 GMT, Content-Length=130, Connection=keep-alive,
>   x-amzn-RequestId=8f57fab6-be57-11e8-a99b-2ba9ede2859c} Sat Sep 22
>   11:06:31 UTC 2018 : Lambda invocation failed with status: 403. Lambda
>   request id: 8f57fab6-be57-11e8-a99b-2ba9ede2859c Sat Sep 22 11:06:31
>   UTC 2018 : Execution failed due to configuration error:  Sat Sep 22
>   11:06:31 UTC 2018 : Method completed with status: 500

I'm not sure what I need, here is my code:

```
variable "app_version" {
}
variable "region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}
variable account_id {
  default = "412092673045"
}


provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "example" {
  function_name = "EXAMPLE"

  # The bucket name as created earlier with "aws s3api create-bucket"
  s3_bucket = "example-core"
  s3_key    = "v${var.app_version}/main.zip"

  # "main" is the filename within the zip file (main.js) and "handler"
  # is the name of the property under which the handler function was
  # exported in that file.
  handler = "main"
  runtime = "go1.x"

  role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn}"

  environment={
    variables = {
      REDIS_URL = "XXXXXXXX"
      REDIS_PASSWORD = "XXXXXXX"
    }
  }
}

# IAM role which dictates what other AWS services the Lambda function
# may access.
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_exec" {
  name = "serverless_example_lambda"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_api_gateway" {
    function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.example.function_name}"
    statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromApiGateway"
    action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    principal = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.arn}"
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "example" {
  name        = "ServerlessExample"
  description = "Terraform Serverless Application Example"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "proxy" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  parent_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id}"
  path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id}"
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_method.proxy.resource_id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.proxy.http_method}"

  integration_http_method = "ANY"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:function:${aws_lambda_function.example.function_name}/invocations"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy_root" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.root_resource_id}"
  http_method   = "ANY"
  authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.resource_id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.http_method}"

  integration_http_method = "ANY"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:function:${aws_lambda_function.example.function_name}/invocations"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "example" {
  depends_on = [
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda",
    "aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root",
  ]

  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id}"
  stage_name  = "api"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
  statement_id  = "AllowAPIGatewayInvoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.example.arn}"
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  # The /*/* portion grants access from any method on any resource
  # within the API Gateway "REST API".
  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.execution_arn}/*/*"
}

output "base_url" {
  value = "${aws_api_gateway_deployment.example.invoke_url}"
}
resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_logging" {
  name = "lambda_logging"
  path = "/"
  description = "IAM policy for logging from a lambda"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "lambda_logs" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.lambda_exec.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.lambda_logging.arn}"
}
```

Comment: You should really edit the code in to your question rather than link to it or at least try to create an [mvce] that you post here. Anyway your `source_arn` is wrong on the Lambda permission. It needs to be the thing that invokes the Lambda not the role.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure if the post would allow that much code. The `source_arn` wasn't the issue. My problem was `integration_http_method` was set to `ANY` instead of `POST`

Comment: @JoelHolmes, are you able to find the solution of this one, as I am facing exactly the same issue.